# Manifest merger error in android studio

Tags: android

I get the following error: Please help

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.1) from [com.android.support:design:26.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
>       is also present at [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.1.0).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="package name">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "package name"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.9.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Post your android manifest file please

Comment: May be you are using multiple versions of the Android Support Libraries causes the issue.

Comment: posted the manifest file

Comment: See the answer below, tell me if some issue is here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change your dependencies version like

in your Gradle file

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

add `tools:replace="android:value"` to application tag in your manifest

Answer (score 0):

Change your all support library as same version like

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
```

Always use same version for same type library.

for convenience, you can use same version like this 
Add this line in app level gradle.

```
def mySupportVersion =  "26.1.0"
```

Then your dependency line will look like

```
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$mySupportVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:design:$mySupportVersion"
```

Answer (score 0):

Sync your build version and supported libraries dependencies to the latest version available. And then clean your project. I hope this will resolve your problem.

Worked for me.

Comment: Tried clean, rebuild several times. still not working

Comment: Post your build.gradle file of application level

Comment: posted gradle file

Comment: Try compileSDKVersion to 26.0.3 and with library version 26.1.0 or you can do google for the latest version launched for compileSDKversion and support library and appcompat library.

Comment: Set compileSDKVersion to 26.0.3 and library to version 26.1.0 the rebuild the project

Comment: I implemented the above change and got the following error:
startup failed: build file '/app/build.gradle': 8: unexpected token: 3 @ line 8, column 28. compileSdkVersion 26.0.3 ^  1 error  Open File

Answer (score 0):

Try to add following lines in end of your app module in `build.gradle`.

```
configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            def requested = details.requested
            if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
                if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                    details.useVersion '26.1.0'
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: I get the following error while executing this code: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs